# How can I perform ten-fold cross validation with LibSVM?

Tags: java, python, validation, libsvm

Where can I find an example of using LibSVM (Java/Python) to perform 10-fold cross validation on a data set?

Answer (score 5):

In case of Java;

You can use svm_cross_validation() method which is provided by libsvm.

```
double[] target = new double[svmProblem.l];
svm.svm_cross_validation(svmProblem, svmParameter, 10, target );
```

You should have created your svm_problem and svm_parameter instances (svmProblem and svmParameter in the sample). 3rd parameter of the function is the number of folds, target is the array of predicted label values for each sample of the data set. So, length of the target array should be same with the length of your input data.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something in your question, the `svmutil.py` script in the `python` subdirectory of the `libsvm` package offers a n-fold cross validation mode:

```
-v n: n-fold cross validation mode
```

The `svm_train.java` file in the `java` subdirectory also offers such an option:

```
+"-v n : n-fold cross validation mode\n"
```

You can have a look at those two files for some sample code.